# Check Mark on table View

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, accessoryview

I want it to have folders on a table view. And i mean folders like when one cell is selected, a new page opens up and its only for that one cell. I need help with the checkmark i want when the cell is selected. when the cell is selected, i want it to go to a new page and i want that cell to have a checkmark on it as it goes to the new page, and when we come back to this view, i want the checkmark to vanish so we can select another cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks, Kurt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the accessoryview to make a checkmark, and indicate them with a BOOL when visited. Maybe even remember this information by storing the bool in a NSUserpreference